# $_POST + fopen not working!

Tags: php, post, fopen

So this is fairly weird experience i have had over the last hour.

Say i have a data source that is controlled by a select


`$fileName = "../data/".$_POST["file"];

$fh = fopen($fileName);`

There is a file named "USA" in the data folder.  When the select option starts, jQuery sends this to a PHP file which will open the proper file and get the correct contents out of file and put them into a different select statement.  This does not work (Failed to open the stream error happens)  But thats not the weird part. The weird part is if i use an absolute name rather than post such as...

`$fileName = "../data/USA";

$fh = fopen($fileName);`

I also verified that $_POST["file"] was infact "USA"

Comment: Please check that $_POST["file"] has one of the values you intend to allow, and stop the script if it doesn't. Just gluing it to some directory and using in file functions causes security vulnerability. Imagine that someone might send you something like ../../../system_file_youd_rather_not_make_public as $_POST["file"] value

Comment: already do.  Which is the confusing part!

Comment: Did you tried var_dump($_POST["file"]); and...that file should have an extension...?

Comment: Might be whitespace in the POST field. Sanitize the input.

Comment: The files do not have any extensions, they are just blank files and are named the same thing as my `<select class="countryList">...</select>`

Comment: What var_dump($_POST["file"]); is "saying" after you select and submit?

Comment: I do not exactly understand your post. Does it work with an "absolute path" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = trim($_POST["file"]);
$fileName = "../data/".$file;
$fh = fopen($fileName, "r");
```

Comment: Ohh yes, i do that as well.  I did not copy and paste my code, just typed over a rough version of it.

Comment: Updated it, your $_POST["file"] seems to be having extra data. Trim should remove the spaces around it. Also check what exactly is in $_POST["file"] using var_dump()

Comment: Also, Post your html control which is passing the data to the php file. We can understand better when we see the source. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>` needs to have a name:

```
    <select name="file">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
```

I don't see any in your example. `$_POST['file']` will get the value from the `<option value="1">`

If it still not working add `var_dump($_POST["file"]);` and see what's in there. It should give you something like that `string(1) "USA"`